# Is the heat dissipation or power dissipation of a CPU the same on same voltages?

Tags: cpu

On frequency x a CPU runs at 0,8 Volts. On frequency y the CPU runs at the same voltage, but frequency y is much higher than x.

Question:
Is the heat produced by the CPU on both frequencies the same? (heat, heat dissipation, power loss)

Comment: We need specifics in order to provide an answer. Normally only an increase in voltage would cause a CPU to run hotter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, higher clock frequencies mean more electronic switching going on.  Digital Semiconductors dissipate the most heat while they are switching, so you would be dissipating more power.

Comment: This is correct. However, to add, the increase in power dissipation from increasing frequency is much lower than an for voltage. In other words, +10% frequency at the same voltage will use less power than +10% voltage at the same frequency (in general).